# Exporting a face texture from blender in the metahuman style

Tags: texturing

please feel free to close if not blender-y enough.

**Background**
We are using 3D scanning (Einscan H) to scan faces into metahuman, it's working really well with some tweaking of the mesh in blender.

We'd like to customize these faces further by adjusting the facial textures that metahuman uses to match the scanned faces.  Getting these out of metahuman is easy enough and gives you a nice flat-stretched looking UDIM (I believe) face image and map that you can edit.

**Problem**
The texture that is used on the 3D model of the scan, doesn't share the same type of flattened face image, but is an image with several parts of the face in different areas (as we'd expect from an unwrapped texture).  We can't figure out what the steps are to change this texture from the separate parts, into a single stretched out flattened face. Or even if it is possible.  Some of the basic 3D scanning apps we tried can export in this function so we guess it is.

Happy to be linked to a video / resource / stack answer, but one that is clear on this and doesn't assume that I know a lot about unwrapping or baking.

Thanks